# Fetch only keys from JSON Object using groovy

Tags: json, groovy

This is my JSON Object

```
{
"master": {
   "node": "xyz", 
   "files": [{"type": "modified", "file": "test.txt"}]
   }, 
"testbranch2": {
   "node": "abc", 
   "files": [{"type": "modified", "file": "test.txt"}] 
   }, 
"testbranch": {
   "node": "xxx", 
   "files": [{"type": "modified", "file": "test.txt"}], 
   }
}
```

I need only the object key names, like "master", "testbranch2","testbranch. How do I fetch only the object key names using groovy?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use JsonSlurper

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

def json =  '{ "master": ...'
def test = new JsonSlurper().parseText(json)
//if json comes from file you can do: new JsonSlurper().parse(new File('YOUR_JSON_FILE'))
println test.keySet()
```

Comment: I tried this, I am getting this error `java.lang.NullPointerException`

Comment: where exactly? what is null?

Comment: I was doing some mistake in the code, fixed it. Your solution works, thank you!